# Calling a user control from a back end page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an input text box and a button that runs on myapppage.aspx and when the user clicks the button I want to populate my user control page. How do I call a control in the embedded usercontrol.ascx file in .NET?

Comment: Mean you want to add a usercontrol in your maypage.apx against button click right?

Comment: Expose a public property that provides access to this control or it's relevant properties(like `DataSource` if it's a `GridView` in your `UserControl`, for example).

Comment: Is there any way to do find control? I want to write out some result text to a asp:Literal in my user control from my page backend.

Comment: @chris: my comment still holds true, provide a property, for example `public string Text{get{return MyLiteral.Text;}set{MyLiteral.Text=value;}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a public property in your `UserControl` which exposes the control to the controller (f.e. the `Page`). Since you've mentioned a `Literal` control:

```
public string Text
{
    get{ return MyLiteral.Text; }
    set{ MyLiteral.Text=value; }
}
```

Now you can use it from your page:

```
myUserControl.Text = "Hello World";
```

I would just provide as much as necessary. So i would not return the control itself. Now you could still change the control type without breaking the code. For example if you want to replace the `Literal` with a `TextBox` or a `Label`.